# Transpose/group/pivot Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given that I have the following Pandas DataFrame:
`df =`

| Lttr | Day | Color | Num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Mon | Red | One |
| A | Tue | Blu | One |
| A | Wed | Grn | One |
| A | Wed | Grn | Two |

How could I best go about re-arranging it to something like:

| Lttr | Mon | Tue | Wed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Red | Blu | Grn |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
(df.pivot_table(index='Lttr', columns='Day', values='Color', aggfunc='first')
   .reset_index()
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
 )
```

Output:

```
  Lttr  Mon  Tue  Wed
0    A  Red  Blu  Grn
```

Comment: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: Not with the provided data, please update your question

Comment: Updated original dataset to include a duplicate column, plus an extraneous column.